# Network.fit epochs doesn't find the right number of files to analyze

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I currently am using a keras model for a project.
I loaded my files in the document (under the name train_images). After asking the program to print it's size to verify it, it turns out to contain 1440 images.
However, after building my neural network and asking for a network.fit, i found out that in each of my epochs, the program only "trains" for 45 images, despite giving him the train_images dataset.
Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?
Joined, the fragment of code for the training:

```
Reseau.compile(optimizer ='SGD',loss = "mse",metrics=['accuracy'])
training=Reseau.fit(
    train_images,
    train_labels,
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=5)
```

Comment: It's 45 batches, not images.

Comment: 45 * 32 (default batch size) = 1440